# How can I get the contents of the second page as well with Scrapy for the scenario below?

Tags: scrapy

I have a spider that needs to fetch an array of object where each object has 5 items. 4 items are on the same page and the 5th item is a URL which I need to extract data from and return all 5 items as text. In the code snippet below, explanation is the key that lies on the other page. I need to parse that and add its data along with the other attributes while yielding it.

My current solution when exported to a JSON file shows up as follows. As you notice, my "e" is not resolved. How do I get the data?

```
[
    {
        "q": "How many pairs of integers (x, y) exist such that the product of x, y and HCF (x, y) = 1080?",
        "c": [
            "8",
            "7",
            "9",
            "12"
        ],
        "a": "Choice (C).9",
        "e": "<Request GET http://iim-cat-questions-answers.2iim.com/quant/number-system/hcf-lcm/hcf-lcm_1.shtml>",
        "d": "Hard"
    }
]


class CatSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "catspider"
    start_urls = [
        'http://iim-cat-questions-answers.2iim.com/quant/number-system/hcf-lcm/'
    ]

    def parse_solution(self, response):
        yield response.xpath('//p[@class="soln"]').extract_first()

    def parse(self, response):
        for lis in response.xpath('//ol[@class="z1"]/li'):
            questions = lis.xpath('.//p[@lang="title"]/text()').extract_first()
            choices = lis.xpath(
                './/ol[contains(@class, "xyz")]/li/text()').extract()
            answer = lis.xpath(
                './/ul[@class="exp"]/li/span/span/text()').extract_first()
            explanation = lis.xpath(
                './/ul[@class="exp"]/li[2]/a/@href').extract_first()
            difficulty = lis.xpath(
                './/ul[@class="exp"]/li[last()]/text()').extract_first()
            if questions and choices and answer and explanation and difficulty:
                yield {
                    'q': questions,
                    'c': choices,
                    'a': answer,
                    'e': scrapy.Request(response.urljoin(explanation), callback=self.parse_solution),
                    'd': difficulty
                }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Scrapy is an asynchronous framework, which means none of it's elements are blocking. So `Request` as an object does nothing, it's only stores info for scrapy downloader, thus it means you cannot just call it to download something like you're doing right now.

Common solution for this is to design a crawl chain by carrying your data through callbacks:

```
def parse(self, response):
    item = dict()
    item['foo'] = 'foo is great'
    next_page = 'http://nextpage.com'
    return Request(next_page,
                   callback=self.parse2,
                   meta={'item': item})  # put our item in meta

def parse2(self, response):
    item = response.meta['item']  # take our item from the meta
    item['bar'] = 'bar is great too!'
    return item
```